# Can't issue Vim's :q on execution

Tags: bash, vim

I've got a handy function that makes it easy for me to install plugins via [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) in the [spf13 distribution](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim) of Vim.

```
function vimp() {
    for plugin in "$@"
    do
        echo Bundle \"$plugin\" >> ~/.vimrc.bundles.local
    done
    vim --cmd "BundleInstall!" --cmd "BundleClean" --cmd "q"
    echo "Plugin installation complete"
}
```

Unfortunately, the `q` command never runs. My hope is to do the bundle installation and cleanup before exiting the editor, but that doesn't seem to be working. The other commands *do* work best I can tell.

Until just recently, I was using this command:

```
vim +BundleInstall! +BundleClean +q
```

Which should do roughly the same thing (running the commands after opening files vs. before), but again the `q` doesn't fire. Any ideas how I can make this work, or can anyone explain why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+qa` or `--cmd qa` instead of just `+q` or `--cmd quit`. Usually this has to do with multiple open buffers (try using `+q +q` or `+q +q +q` to verify).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unofrtunately, it doesn't seem to fix the problem in my case. Whether I try `+qa` or several `+q`s, vim stays open. Any other ideas? I can manually quit with `:q`.

Comment: Disregard. I forgot to source my config after making the changes. Works like a charm. Thanks!